# Most idiomatic way of searching by relations in Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a Room search, which requires the Room struct to contain the entire User struct.

```
type Room struct {
    ID        *int64     `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty" gorm:"not null"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`

    User   *User  `json:"user,omitempty"`
    UserID *int64 `json:"user_id,omitempty"`
}
```

and

```
type User struct {
    ID        *int64     `json:"id"`
    CreatedAt *time.Time `json:"created_at,omitempty" gorm:"not null"`
    UpdatedAt *time.Time `json:"updated_at,omitempty"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `json:"deleted_at,omitempty"`

    FirstName *string `json:"first_name,omitempty"`
    LastName  *string `json:"last_name,omitempty"`
}
```

while the search function looks like this

```
func searchRoom(db *gorm.DB, q string) ([]Room, error) {
    q = "%" + q + "%"

    rooms := []Room{}

    db.Preload("User").
        Joins("LEFT JOIN users on rooms.user_id = users.id").
        Where(
            "CONCAT(users.first_name, ' ', users.last_name) LIKE ?",
            q,
        ).
        Find(&rooms)

    return rooms, nil
}
```

This works pretty well the way it is expected, however, to me this looks a bit clunky, I went through Gorm docs, but didn't find anything else which could help me.

I could use the `db.Raw` method, but that does not fill the user struct automatically.

Is there a better way to use Gorm and make it more performant?

Comment: Is your question how to make it faster? If so, why do you think it's performing poorly? Or do you want to know how to make it "less clunky" (whatever that means)?

Comment: 1. I do think it can perform better because normally without Gorm I would use the JOIN statement to get the User data and not make a separate second call on Users table.
2. I want to know how would you put the db methods together? Does this look alright to you?

Comment: If you find yourself working around your ORM, it's time to stop using an ORM.

Comment: (It's always time to stop using an ORM)